# Использование оператора new

Tags: c#

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms379574(v=vs.80)

ссылка на статью

```
public class GraphNode<T> : Node<T>
{
    private List<int> costs;

    public GraphNode() : base() { }
    public GraphNode(T value) : base(value) { }
    public GraphNode(T value, NodeList<T> neighbors) : base(value, neighbors) { }

    new public NodeList<T> Neighbors // зачем здесь new?
    {
        get
        {
            if (base.Neighbors == null)
                base.Neighbors = new NodeList<T>();

            return base.Neighbors;
        }            
    }

    public List<int> Costs
    {
        get
        {
            if (costs == null)
                costs = new List<int>();

            return costs;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это не оператор `new`, а модификатор `new`, показывающий компилятору, что программист знает о том, что перекрывает (ре-декларирует) свойство/метод/т.п., существующее под таким же именем в базовом классе, и делает это намеренно.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-modifier

Три вида `new`:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new